# I have a discord.py issue as time.sleep stops the whole thing

Tags: python

I have been making a discord.py pet bot recently and have come across an issue where `time.sleep()` just stops the entire bot from working.

```
# bot.py
import os
import time
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = ('Bot_ID')
GUILD={'Guild_Name'}
hunger=100#hits 0 in 24 hrs(-1 every 864 secs)
happy=100#hits 0 in 6 hrs(-1 every 216 secs)
thirst=100#hits 0 in 12 hrs(-1 every 432 secs)
clean=100#hits 0 in 48 hrs (-1 every 1728 secs)
health=100#the health dont let it hit 0...
life='alive'#Alive or Dead
p='p'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name==GUILD:
            break
        
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to thr following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id:{guild.id})'
    )

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global hunger
    global happy
    global thirst
    global clean
    global health
    global life
    global p
    if message.author==client.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.content==(p+'Start'):
        re='Hello'
        await message.channel.send(re)
        while True:
            time.sleep(1728)
            clean-=1
            if clean<0:
                clean=0
                health-=1
            elif clean<26:
                await message.channel.send('im getting dirty')
            if health<26:
                await message.channel.send('<@&773151702827794463> Help Im Dying')
    if message.content==(p+'Start'):
        while True:
            time.sleep(864)
            hunger-=1
            if hunger<0:
                hunger=0
                health-=1
            elif hunger<26:
                await message.channel.send('im getting hungry')
            if health<26:
                await message.channel.send('<@&773151702827794463> Help Im Dying')
    if message.content==(p+'Start'):
        while True:
            time.sleep(432)
            thirst-=1
            if thirst<0:
                thirst=0
                health-=1
            elif thirst<26:
                await message.channel.send('im getting thirsty')
            if health<26:
                await message.channel.send('<@&773151702827794463> Help Im Dying')
    if message.content==(p+'Start'):
        while True:
            time.sleep(261)
            happy-=1
            if happy<0:
                happy=0
                health-=1
            elif happy<26:
                await message.channel.send('im getting sad')
            if health<26:
                await message.channel.send('<@&773151702827794463> Help Im Dying')
    if message.content==(p+'feed'):
        await message.channel.send('Thanks for the food')
        hunger=100
    if message.content==(p+'drink'):
        await message.channel.send('Thanks for the water')
        thirst=100
    if message.content==(p+'play'):
        await message.channel.send('Yay fun')
        happy=100
    if message.content==(p+'clean'):
        await message.channel.send('Nice and Clean')
        clean=100
    if message.content==(p+'pstats'):
        await message.channel.send('State:',alive)
        await message.channel.send('Health:',health)
        await message.channel.send('Hunger:',hunger)
        await message.channel.send('Thirst:',thirst)
        await message.channel.send('Cleanliness:',clean)
        await message.channel.send('Happiness:',happy)
    if health<0:
        await message.channel.send('<@&773151702827794463> Your Pet Has Died')
        health=0
        life='Dead'
        
    
            
            
        
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: That's exactly what `time.sleep` is supposed to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Discord.py \`time.sleep()\` coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147936/python-discord-py-time-sleep-coroutine)

Comment: For this I imagine the `asyncio` or `threading` module will be best

Comment: Not really because i would like to keep it all under one async def

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that. I mean you could calculate the time that each action should be run, then when that time comes or passes (just in case) you trigger the action and calculate a new time?

Comment: i might just have to spend an hour rewriting most of it

Comment: Ok, taking a fresh look at the code, you'll either have to rearrange it into a single while loop with a seperate event handler, use seperate async functions, or add multithreading for different functions and timers.

Comment: i have separated the async functions and it broke

Answer (score 0):

Use **asyncio.sleep()**

```
import asyncio

....
if message.content==(p+'Start'):
    re='Hello'
    await message.channel.send(re)
    while True:
        #time.sleep(1728)
        await asyncio.sleep(1728)
        ....
```