# One of my embeds aren't working, but my other 2 with the nearly same code, are

Tags: python, discord.py

I have 3 embeds. 2 of them show the correct embeds, but one of them just shows a blank embed. the codes are nearly the same, so I don't know whats wrong. Here is my code for my function:

**My code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def slots(ctx, amount = None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
    
  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send("How ya gonna slots 0 coins, dum dum")
    return
    
  bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
    
  amount = int(amount)
  if amount>(bal[0]+1):
    await ctx.send("You don't even have that many coins, idiot")
    return
  if amount<0:
    await ctx.send("You wanna lose money by gambling negative coins?")
    return
    
  final = []
  for i in range(3):
    a = random.choice([":egg:", ":baby_chick:", ":hatching_chick:",":hatched_chick:",':poultry_leg:',':chicken:'])
    final.append(a)
    
  em = Embed(title = f"{ctx.author}s Slots Game", color = discord.Color.lighter_grey())
  em.add_field(name = final, value = f"\n{ctx.author}s Slots Game", inline = False)
  msg = await ctx.send(embed = em)
    
  if final[0] == final[1] or final[0] == final[2] or final[1] == final[2]:
    await update_bank(ctx.author, 2*amount)
    em_new = Embed(title = f"{ctx.author}s Slots Game", color = discord.Color.green())
    em_new.add_field(name = final, value = f"\n{ctx.author}s Slots Game", inline = False)
    em_new.add_field(name = "Win!", value = f"You won {2*amount} coins!")
    sleep(1)
    await msg.edit(embed=em_new)
    if final[0] == final[1] == final[2]:
      await update_bank(ctx.author, 3*amount)
      em_new = Embed(title = f"{ctx.author}s Slots Game", color = discord.Color.green())
      em_new.add_field(name = final, value = f"\n{ctx.author}s Slots Game", inline = False)
      em_new.add_field(name = "Win!", value = f"You won {3*amount} coins!")
      sleep(1)
      await msg.edit(embed=em_new)
  else:
    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount)
    em_new = Embed(title = f"{ctx.author}s Slots Game", color = discord.Color.red())
    em_new.add_field(name = final, value = f"\n{ctx.author}s Slots Game", inline = False)
    em_new = discord.Embed(name = "Loss!", value = f"You lost {-1*amount} coins.")
    sleep(1)
    await msg.edit(embed=em_new)
```

the first 2 if statement embed things are working, they edit and show what they're supposed to show. But the else statement embed just shows a blank embed. can someone pls help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line of code

```py
em_new = discord.Embed(name = "Loss!", value = f"You lost {-1*amount} coins.")
```

You are calling an embed via `discord.Embed` while in all other cases you are using `Embed` by itself.
Considering that all embeds except for this work I assume your imports look similar to the following:

```py
from discord import Embed
```

With this import structure you do not need to specify `discord.Embed`
So change the line of code to the following:

```
em_new = Embed(name = "Loss!", value = f"You lost {-1*amount} coins.")
```

Additionally I should remark that you should probably replace `time.sleep` with its asyncio equivalent. You can find more info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147936/python-discord-py-time-sleep-coroutine/61148845#61148845).