# How to set a timer in discord.py while enabling other codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to set a time for, say `30 seconds`, but having other commands available during the timer period. I cannot do `time.sleep(30)` since that will disable the ability for the bot to respond to other commands. Is there a way for a bot to receive a message and respond after `30 seconds` while the bot is able to receive and perform other commands? A possible chat log may be below:

```
user: !timer 30
bot:  Timer set for 30 seconds
user: Hello
bot:  Hi
bot:  Your timer of 30 seconds has ended. (after 30 seconds are up)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Discord.py \`time.sleep()\` coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147936/python-discord-py-time-sleep-coroutine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `asyncio` library. `asyncio.sleep()` works in background and doesn't block other functions. Learn more about [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine).

```py
@client.command()
async def timer(ctx, seconds):
    try:
        seconds= int(seconds)
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("Please provide a valid time")
        return
    await ctx.send(f"Your timer has started for {seconds} seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds) # This is the sleep method.
    await ctx.send("Your timer ended!")
    return
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the ```f``` here for in ```line 8```

Comment: Glad it helper. Also, that `f` is called f-string. It's a new addition in Python 3.6. You can use it in place of `.format()`. As you see in the message, I did `{seconds}` that's because I put an `f` before string. :)

Comment: Oh that makes it neater. Although I do prefer "Your timer has started for '' + str(seconds) + " seconds." because I'm not super clear with .format() lol.

Comment: .format() basically replaces `{}` in code. for example `print("Hello {} I'm {}".format(ctx.author.name, client.user.name))` this returns "Hello Username, I'm Botname". You can add more then two `{}`.

Comment: So if I use `f` in front of the message, do I just put the things in the parentheses inside the `{}`? For your example, do I simply put `print(f."Hello {ctx.author.name} I'm {client.user.name}")` if I want to print out the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use timer objects in python, example:

```py
import threading
def do_something():
    print("do something")
    #or tell the user that his time ended

timer = threading.Timer(30, do_something)
timer.start() #you would probably want to start the timer whenever the user types the command
```

you can find some reference [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timer-objects-python/#:%7E:text=Timer%20is%20a%20sub%20class,corresponding%20to%20the%20timer%20explicitly.&text=Create%20a%20timer%20that%20will,after%20interval%20seconds%20have%20passed.)

Comment: You don't need threading for this, just a simple `asyncio.sleep` would do the job, and besides threading.timer is also synchronous and will result in the same delay

Comment: it's one of the choices, at least it does the job as a timer

Comment: Yes, but I think it will result in the stopping of other commands since it is not asynchronously executed

Comment: yeah but that timer object is run in a separate thread when you call `start()`, so it will not interrupt the main thread from running.

Comment: Oh ok. I should have tested that. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works. The solution below seems freer to use if repeatedly though.