# @tasks.loop() stopping commands from running until the loop is finished

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I have a background loop involving selenium, so it takes a long time to finish executing. I noticed that the bot had a delay when responding to commands, and I found out that the processes inside `@tasks.loop()` needs to finish before the commands execute. For example:

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import time

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hi')

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def loop():
    print('h')
    time.sleep(20)
    print('i')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    loop.start()

bot.run()
```

Here, if you do `-test` after it prints the letter *h* and before it prints the letter *i*, the bot will not respond until it prints the *i* and the loop finishes.

How would I make it so that the commands will be able to execute along with the loop? FYI my code doesn't have a `time.sleep()`,  it was just an example.

Comment: long-running code you have to run in separated thread.

Comment: @furas How would I do that?

Comment: python has modules [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) for this. You should find many tutorials for this. `t = threading.Thread(target=function_name)` and `t.start()` - so first you have to put code in new function. And later use `Thread` in `loop`. BTW: `target needs  function's name without `()` - it will later use `()` to run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Discord.py \`time.sleep()\` coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147936/python-discord-py-time-sleep-coroutine)

Comment: @duckboycool No, as I said there are no `time.sleep()` in my loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have long running code then you should move it into separated function and run it with `threading` or `multiprocessing.

Here basic example with `threading`. It runs new thread in every loop. For something more complex it may need different menthod. It may need to run single thread before `discord` and use `queue` in `loop` to send information to thread.

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import time
import threading
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hi')

def long_running_function():
    print('long_running_function: start')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('long_running_function: end')
    
@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def loop():
    print('h')
    t = threading.Thread(target=long_running_function)
    t.start()
    print('i')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    loop.start()

bot.run(os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN'))
```

Comment: This works very well, but I just realized I have `await` inside the loop, and when I try to run it it gives me a syntax error. How would I solve that?

Comment: better create new question on new page - you will have place to show current code and full error message.