# How to use asyncio with multithreading?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a discord bot which has a `tasks.loop()` which has loop inside it that takes a while to execute and slows down commands as I have further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478409/tasks-loop-stopping-commands-from-running-until-the-loop-is-finished). I was suggested to use `threading` for the code inside the `tasks.loop()` and then start it when the loop is run.

However, I have an `await` inside that function and when I try to run it I get `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`. How would I use threading and async/await together?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to run coroutines in another thread, nonetheless you can do it with [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe)

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def coroutine():
    return await asyncio.sleep(10, "Coroutine")    


coro = coroutine() # Getting the coroutine object

future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop) # returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` instance
result = future.result()
print(result)
```

Also take a look at one of my previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881761/discord-gateway-warning-shard-id-none-heartbeat-blocked-for-more-than-10-second/65882269#65882269) to run blocking functions in a non-blocking way (you're not gonna have to mess with `concurrent.futures.Future` and `threading`, just with asyncio, a much easier way)

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand this code and don't know how I would incorporate it in my current code. What I'm trying to do is have discord send a message using `ctx.send()` within the long-running code, which needs `await`.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a separate thread? I assumed that the functions inside of them are blocking, to run a blocking function in a non-blocking way refer to the link in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your code is blocking you may want to take a look at `run_in_executor` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Of if your code is asynchronous use `loop.create_task`

It's usually not a good idea to use threading on an asynchronous program.