# Delete bot's message automatically Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm coding in Python and started coding recently. I created super simple clockwork mini machine in Python:

```
if message.content.startswith("Clock"):
    await message.channel.send("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    await message.channel.send("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    await message.channel.send("1")
```

But now I want to make the bot delete previous message automatically, so it would look like single message turning into 3, 2, 1

Sincere thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delete_after parameter,

```py
 message.channel.send("3", delete_after=1)
```

This will delete the message after 1 second, without blocking your code.

References:-

- [Messagable.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

Note: Don't use `time.sleep` it blocks your entire code. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147936/python-discord-py-time-sleep-coroutine)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
if message.content.startswith("Clock"):
    MessageOne = await message.channel.send("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    await MessageOne.delete()
    MessageTwo = await message.channel.send("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    await MessageTwo.delete()
    MessageThree = await message.channel.send("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    await MessageThree.delete()
```

Comment: Instead of time.sleep(1), you should use `await asyncio.sleep(1)`. That way it lets the rest of the program continue while running.

Comment: Now that I look at it, you should definitely use the method Ceres suggested instead, best of luck